# How to use a plugin for input validation when using AngularJS Controllers?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I have a little problem when building my first AngularJS + C# web app. We have a plugin here (jQuery) which allow us to call a method from any input, and a little warning appears over the input field. The method works likes

```
user_email.warning('invalid email');
```

this is very simple to us. The `user_email` is an HTML element (`input type='text'`) where I want to show the balloon.

But with angularJS I don't know how can I achieve this. I'm from my controller calling the web service. The webservice returns me 'invalid email/email is in use' and I need to send this warning, but inside the controller "I don't know which input is it". It's obvious I have the right `name` and `id` of field but, it sounds weird if the controller calls this method.

Can I have help about the concepts and if it's a good approach or not?

Comment: Do not tag your question with [tag:jquery-validate] unless that's the actual plugin you're using.  Based on the code you've shown, I removed your tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Majority of dom manipulation is done from directive. You can define a custom directive and I think that will do the trick.

```
//Inside directive
var ddo = {  //directive definition object
    scope : {
      msg : '=message'
    },
    link : function(scope, el, attrs) {
        angular.element(el).warning(scope.msg);
    }
}

//In html
<input my-directive message="someVar" />

//In controller
controllerScope.someVar = /* call to your web service */
```

Edit: Adding blogs

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607873/Extending-HTML-with-AngularJS-Directives
http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/a-directive-to-manage-file-upload-in-an-angularjs-application

Its not blog but some good directive implementations. Sometimes seeing examples and how they work helps in understanding
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: I'm looking for directive and how to use it. Any bigger sample or blog post about?

Comment: Can you give me the name of jquery plugin. I can create a plunker demo if its simple. Also, I will add blog posts on directives.

Comment: This plugin was develop here (on my job, by the jquery guys). I dont know if its on the web avaiable. But we call the warning or error ballon just setting input.warning or input.error